# In R, how to return vector of indexes across a vector, assuming multiple condition vectors?

Tags: r, indexing

I want to return the index of a vector position across an entire vector.

For example,

```
a = c(0,10,20,30) #lower bound
b = c(10,20,30,40) #upper bound
values = c(1,5,24,30)

#I want idx to return the index of a/b across all elements in values
# I was hoping this would work:
idx = which(a<=values & b>values)

#I can get it if I do a for loop but I want to avoid a for loop
idx = c(0)
for(i in 1:length(values)){
    idx[i]= which(a<=values[i] & b>values[i])  

 }
```

Comment: `sapply(values, function(x) which(a<=x & b>x))`?

Comment: `findInterval(values, unique(c(a, b)))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just to put an answer on this question both the comments above work.

```
findInterval(values, unique(c(a, b)))
```

This answer by Henrik uses lesser known function `findInterval` from the base package. This function has several arguments that may make it adaptible to most situations.

```
sapply(values, function(x) which(a<=x & b>x))
```

This answer by d.p takes the OP's loop and adapts it to work in `sapply`. This may be a better option if you cannot remember the `findInterval` or if you just want to more directly control what is going on.